# Too many indices for array while slicing

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I am getting error "IndexError: too many indices for array" when i try slice.

I can print every field of array, as you can see below:

```
vector = np.random.choice(data)
print(vector)
vec1 = vector[-1]
print(vec1)
vec2 = vector[1]
print(vec2)
```

> (5.5, 2.5, 4., 1.3, 'Iris-versicolor')
>
> Iris-versicolor
>
> 2.5

When i add that line:

```
vec3 = vector[:-1]
```

I am getting error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

What could possible be the problem here?

//Edit

I take my data from iris file

```
names = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'class']
data = np.genfromtxt('iris.data', delimiter=',', dtype=None, encoding=None, names=names)
```

I also check type of vecotr

```
print(type(vector))
```

> class 'numpy.void'

Comment: You really ought to post a [mcve] when asking debugging questions.

Comment: Initializing `vector = (5.5, 2.5, 4., 1.3, 'Iris-versicolor')`, I'm not getting any error. So there must be something else causing the issue. Please give a *complete* example.

Comment: `genfromtxt` with those parameters returns a structured array.  Look at the `data.dtype` and `data.shape`.  `vector` is then a single element array of the same `dtype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially the same explanation as @user2357112:

```
In [82]: data = np.array([(5.5, 2.5, 4., 1.3, 'Iris-versicolor')],dtype='f,f,f,f,U20')
In [83]: vector = np.random.choice(data)
In [84]: vector
Out[84]: (5.5, 2.5, 4., 1.3, 'Iris-versicolor')
In [85]: vector[-1]
Out[85]: 'Iris-versicolor'
In [86]: vector[1]
Out[86]: 2.5
In [87]: vector[:-1]
IndexError: too many indices for array
In [88]: vector.dtype
Out[88]: dtype([('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<U20')])
In [89]: vector['f2']
Out[89]: 4.0
```

`data` may have more elements, but `choice` without further parameters returns just one, as a 0d array (`vector.shape`).

Normally we index fields of structured array with the field names, but it is possible to access them by number.  But it isn't possible to access them by slice.

The record can be extracted with `item`, yielding a `tuple`:

```
In [90]: vector.item()
Out[90]: (5.5, 2.5, 4.0, 1.2999999523162842, 'Iris-versicolor')
In [91]: _[:-1]
Out[91]: (5.5, 2.5, 4.0, 1.2999999523162842)
```

It is also possible to access multiple fields with a list:

```
In [92]: vector.dtype.names
Out[92]: ('f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4')
In [93]: vector.dtype.names[:-1]
Out[93]: ('f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3')
In [95]: vector[list(vector.dtype.names[:-1])]
Out[95]: (5.5, 2.5, 4., 1.3)
```

But this multifield name code has been undergoing developement, so the details may vary from release to release.

Comment: Oh yeah, `item()` exists. I tend to forget about `item()` and stick with `tolist()`.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a single record extracted from a NumPy structured array or something similar. This record looks like a tuple, but it's actually an instance of `numpy.void`, `numpy.record`, or some related type. To convert it into a tuple, you can use

```
tup = vector.tolist()
```

(yes, `tolist()` for a tuple), and then you can perform ordinary tuple operations on the result, including slicing.

Comment: This is a reasonable explanation, although then the exception should already be raised at `vec2 = vector[1]`.

Comment: @Falko: `numpy.void` and `numpy.record` support indexing, but not slicing. I believe slicing would lead to messy decisions regarding memory layout and padding, but I'm not fully aware of the problems involved.